# Problema al descargar un Excel desde Frontend Angular

Tags: angular, excel, frontend

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 downloadExcelErrors(idArchivoResultado: string): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.apiService.request(
                'post',
                'producto/DescargarErroresActualizacionMasiva?fileUniqueId=' + idArchivoResultado
                ,{ responseType: 'blob' }
            ).toPromise().then((response: any) => {
                const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const a = document.createElement('a');

                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'Errores_Actualizacion_Masiva.xlsx';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                resolve();
            }, (error) => {
                reject(error);
            });      
    }
}
```

El problema es en el Frontend, en el Backend funciona bien. Quisiera saber porque al darle descargar me sale ese error en la consola :(.
Gracias, espero una ayuda.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estas queriendo descargar un Excel con ciertos datos que tu programa regresa?